# UIPageViewController how to remove shadow while page curl

Tags: curl, uipageviewcontroller, shadow

I have an app in which I am using `UIPageViewController` for `curl effect`, the problem is that my page has background image and some `transparent border` so when page `curl` to other page the `transparent layer` look like glass of `transparent layer` which shadow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave Library solve my problem, please follow the link

https://github.com/brow/leaves